# "Your communities" is shown (and empty) for logged out users in the super-collider

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar

The modified design for the top-bar drop down looks great for logged in users, but when logged out, it looks like this;

> [image]

It'd be nice if this area was either removed completely for logged out users (preferred) or otherwise some message is shown.

I guess this would also be applicable to users who are part of only one community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're gonna hide that section for anonymous users and folks with only one active site. Should go out in the next build.